# How to automatically adjust height based on label content inside collection view cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, height, uicollectionviewcell

[image: Collection View Cell Like this]

I want to achieve a self resizing height collection view cell (image above) using swift. I have tried many options like `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and `sizeforItem`. Nothing works for me. I want to achieve similar result like in the image

Comment: I don't think you need a `UICollectionView`. Make it an `UITableView` and build your cell using a horizontal `UIStackView`.

Comment: How can we do that? Can u pls guide me, i am a newbie @NeoOnJupiter

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001569/make-tableview-with-multiple-columns

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Set Estimate size to automatic and do not implement sizeForItemAt , In CollectionView Cell, for each label give number of lines to zero. It will resize automatically.

Set Min spacing and line Spacing to zero as well

[image]

Also, In the collection View cell, three labels should be in stackView with fill alignment and distribution , set multiplier to center label width as 0.6 ( or whatever you want ) of total cell width. Give equal width constraint to first and last label like this image :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then how will I be able to achieve a 3x3 collectionview cell (see image) , without using sizeForItemAt

Comment: @VishnuNair I have updated my answer. please check